# A single component displaying different information based on passed arguments

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have two separate components. One is a Modal generator that creates a modal based on the information that is passed to it and the second component just calls that ModalComponent with the relevant information.

I have a set up where on the single page I want to call the same ModalComponent but with two different arguments. So when you click on them the first one will display the first set of information and the second will display the second set of information. The issue is that they're both displaying the first set of information. Explaining this in code would be easier:

**modals.component.html:**

This is where I define what a model looks like. 'title' and 'content' are the arguments accepted by this modal in the .ts file and displayed here.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary"
     data-toggle="modal"
     data-target="#modal"
     style="height: 400px; width: 400px;">
  Launch demo modal
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
          {{title}}
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**modals.component.ts**

This is where the input into the Modal is accepted under 'title' and 'content'.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modals',
  templateUrl: './modals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modals.component.css']
})

export class ModalsComponent implements OnInit{


  @Input('title') title: string;
  @Input('content') content: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**awareness.component.html**

Here I call the modals in the HTML page. So when I click on one of the divs a modal should be created (which it is) and the content specified should be shown. However in all cases only 'Title 1' and 'Content 1' is shown regardless which div is clicked on.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      Below you can find more information about vaccinations.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <app-modals [title]="'Title 1'" [content]="'Content 1'"></app-modals>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <app-modals [title]="'Title 2'" [content]="'Content 2'"></app-modals>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you only ever have the one `id` value, "modal". When you then use something like `document.querySelector('#modal')` or `document.getElementById('modal')` you will only get the first one.

Instead, either require a unique ID to be passed into your component, or generate one automatically using something like `this.id = 'modal' + modalId++;`.

**modals.component.html**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary"
     data-toggle="modal"
     [attr.data-target]="'#' + id"
     style="height: 400px; width: 400px;">
  Launch demo modal
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" [id]="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
          {{title}}
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**modals.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

let modalId = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modals',
  templateUrl: './modals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modals.component.css']
})

export class ModalsComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() content: string;
  id = `modal${modalId++}`; // generate the unique ID

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```